# google maps api v3 places autocomplete only for selected city

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

when user starts to type city, autosuggest only suggests cities within 50 miles of tampa, FL (or anything else )

```
var southWest = new google.maps.LatLng( 28.3914,-81.936035 );
    var northEast = new google.maps.LatLng( 28.3914,-81.936035 );
    var hyderabadBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds( southWest, northEast );

    var options = {
        bounds: hyderabadBounds,
        types:  ['geocode'],
        componentRestrictions: { country: 'us' }
    };

    var input1 = document.getElementById('search_header');
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input1,options);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using the same LatLng for NorthEast and SouthWest of hyderabadBounds, use a LatLngBounds-object that encompasses the desired area, e.g.:

```
bounds: new google.maps.Circle({center:new google.maps.LatLng( 28.3914,-81.936035 ),
                                radius:50000}).getBounds()
```

Note: there is no guarantee that the Automplete restricts the results to the given bounds